# Using margin on flex items

Tags: css, flexbox

I was under the impression that a margin can be added to flex items/children, and flexbox should automatically take that into account and calculate the correct spacing between the items.

I can't seem to get this working as I would like though.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/dba5ehcw/1/

```
.flex-item{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 160px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

So each flex item at the moment is half the width of the container, and they flow nicely next to each other.

I would like to be able to add a margin of say, 1em to the flex-items in order to give them some breathing room, but in doing so, they become larger than the 50% and no longer stack next to each other on the same line because they are too wide.

Is there a way to use margin on the flex-items and have the flexbox container take this into account and adjust (decrease) their widths accordingly?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to do it with padding - which, when in `border-box` mode does not make the container larger than it's specified width - not margin, and a nested `flex` div. This is how all flexbox-based grid systems work. Code below:

```css
.flex-container{
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 320px;
}

.flex-item{
    padding:1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 160px;
    width: 50%;
    display:flex;
}

.flex-item>div {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item"><div></div></div>
    <div class="flex-item"><div></div></div>
    <div class="flex-item"><div></div></div>
    <div class="flex-item"><div></div></div>
    <div class="flex-item"><div></div></div>
    <div class="flex-item"><div></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This got it, thanks. I had tried padding previously - but without the nested div.

Comment: Well, padding != margin. The answer with calc(50% - margin) is obviously better.

Answer (score 63):

There are multiple ways to do this:

- Use `calc`:

  ```css
  .flex-item {
    width: calc(50% - 2em);
    margin: 1em;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  .flex-container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 320px;
  }
  .flex-item {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: calc(160px - 2em);
    width: calc(50% - 2em);
    margin: 1em;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item"></div>
    <div class="flex-item"></div>
    <div class="flex-item"></div>
    <div class="flex-item"></div>
    <div class="flex-item"></div>
    <div class="flex-item"></div>
  </div>
  ```
- Use nested boxes:

  ```css
  .flex-item {
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
  }
  .flex-item > div {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    flex: 1;
    margin: 1em;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  .flex-container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 320px;
  }
  .flex-item {
    height: 160px;
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
  }
  .flex-item > div {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    flex: 1;
    margin: 1em;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item"><div></div></div>
    <div class="flex-item"><div></div></div>
    <div class="flex-item"><div></div></div>
    <div class="flex-item"><div></div></div>
    <div class="flex-item"><div></div></div>
    <div class="flex-item"><div></div></div>
  </div>
  ```
- Place each row in a nowrap container, and use a positive flex-shrink factor

  ```css
  .row {
    display: flex;
  }
  .flex-item {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 1em;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  .flex-container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 320px;
  }
  .row {
    height: 160px;
    display: flex;
  }
  .flex-item {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 1em;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="flex-item"></div>
      <div class="flex-item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="flex-item"></div>
      <div class="flex-item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="flex-item"></div>
      <div class="flex-item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```
- Don't use `width`. Instead, force line-breaks at the right places, and use `flex: 1` to make the elements grow to fill remaining space.

  ```css
  .flex-item {
    flex: 1;
  }
  .line-break {
    width: 100%
  }
  ```

  ```css
  .flex-container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 320px;
  }
  .flex-item {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: calc(160px - 2em);
    flex: 1;
    margin: 1em;
  }
  .line-break {
    width: 100%;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item"></div>
    <div class="flex-item"></div>
    <div class="line-break"></div>
    <div class="flex-item"></div>
    <div class="flex-item"></div>
    <div class="line-break"></div>
    <div class="flex-item"></div>
    <div class="flex-item"></div>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: This answer should be the accepted, providing loads of alternatives

Comment: Ya `calc` seems like the most semantic solution when possible.

Answer (score 17):

instead of using margins, try adding a gap on your flex container

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    gap: 1em 
}
flex-item {
    width 50%
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this : -

```css
.flex-container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 320px;
}

.flex-item {
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 1%;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 160px;
  width: 48%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe I was trying to achieve the same thing, from my understanding, with the addition that I wanted the two boxes to stack on top of each other when the viewport gets small enough (when viewing on mobile/tablet).

For some reason I thought this would be way easier as I saw something similar in a Bootstrap tutorial video I watched but I think he was using `row` and `col` classes, with a `g` gutter class, and not Flex.

Anyway, HTML:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap flex-half-screen-responsive">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flex-half-screen-responsive {
    margin: -0.5em;
}

.flex-half-screen-responsive > * {
    flex: 1 1 48%;
    margin: 0.5em;
}
```

I don't like how I have to specify that hardcoded 48% value but it seems to work just as I want it so whatever; spent way too much time on this already lol. Anyway I hope this helps someone looking for the same behavior.