# Flexbox not playing nice in safari

Tags: css, flexbox

First site I'm using flexbox on, so somewhat of a learning curve...

Basically the layout works perfectly in Chrome:

[image]

http://richmond-new.streeten.co.uk/index

But is entirely screwed in Safari:

[image]

I fear this is probably very much complicated by my attempting to replicate a grid system with gutters around each element, something I was assisted with here: [Using margin on flex items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32765039/using-margin-on-flex-items)

I am using prefixes where (I believe) necessary - on the container:

```
.index{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

And on the children in that container:

```
.mainImage{
    -webkit-box-flex: 1 1 66.66%;
    -moz-box-flex: 1 1 66.66%;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 66.66%;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 66.66%;
    flex: 1 1 66.66%;
}
```

The percentage used for the flex-basis does vary for each of the elements, depending on how much of the row I want them to take up. i.e. some are 25%, 33.33% etc.

The HTML structure is as follows (I've removed all but one article to try and keep it short):

```
<section class="pageContent index">
    <article class="mainImage">
        <div>
            <a href="#">
                <div class="articleContent">
                    <h1>Marketing Services for Growing Businesses</h1>
                    <h2>The Richmond Marketing Consultancy specialises in providing marketing services to SME, B2B and Professional Service firms.</h2>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </article>
</section>
```

Any help much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Tried to pull together some more CSS as requested. Not sure exactly what you needed but I've tried to pull in what's relevant. As mentioned in my comment, the site is also available to view online too at http://richmond-new.streeten.co.uk/index if you need to see the live code:

```
.pageContent {
  *zoom: 1;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
}

.pageContent:before,
.pageContent:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.pageContent:after {
  clear: both;
}

.pageContent > div {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}

.index {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

article > div {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.mainImage,
  .markServ {
    height: 340px;
  }

.index .mainImage > div {
  background-image: url("/images/main.jpg");
}

.mainImage {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1 1 66.66%;
    -moz-box-flex: 1 1 66.66%;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 66.66%;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 66.66%;
    flex: 1 1 66.66%;
  }

.markServ,
  .caseOne,
  .busDev,
  .twit {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1 1 33.33%;
    -moz-box-flex: 1 1 33.33%;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 33.33%;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 33.33%;
    flex: 1 1 33.33%;
  }

  .headline {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1 1 100%;
    -moz-box-flex: 1 1 100%;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 100%;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 100%;
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    min-height: 0;
  }

  .outsourced {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1 1 50%;
    -moz-box-flex: 1 1 50%;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 50%;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 50%;
    flex: 1 1 50%;
  }

  .blog,
  .caseTwo {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1 1 25%;
    -moz-box-flex: 1 1 25%;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 25%;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 25%;
    flex: 1 1 25%;
  }
```

Comment: can you provide more css? there isn't enough to reproduce the issue you are getting. it just looks like two links

Comment: Also, what version of Safari?

Comment: Safari version is 8.0.8. I'm not sure what more css to provide without bloating the question too much, but will look into that now and add some more.

Comment: The site is available online if that helps - I did put the link in the original post but it was underneath a screenshot so may not have been immediately obvious. Here it is for now, I will also add more css to the original question: http://richmond-new.streeten.co.uk/index