# Right edge of navbar is not showing - setting right margin does not resolve issue

Tags: html, css, layout, margin

I have been trying to create two side by side navbars over the past few days.  I have gotten over most of the issues faced but have an annoying niggle left.  The very right edge of the navbar does not show.  I have a workaround( set the width to 99% ) but I would like to to understand the reason why it is not appearing.  It seems that you get an automatic margin on the left hand side, but not right.
I've searched this site amongst other, but they appear to have the opposite problem!
Adding right-margin statement at various places impacts the content, but not the navbar.

I have checked the output in Mozilla and Chrome to make sure it wasn't the browser.

Couple of images to clarify:

Navbar when at 100%

[image: Navbar when at 100%]

And at 99% set( the workaround )

Navbar at 99%

[image: Navbar at 99%]

Here is the HTML code.  Go easy on me, I am a beginner in CSS on a steep learning curve!  Started with Bootstrap but came to the realization that without knowing the basics, BootStrap would be a life of copy pasta( plus all the bloat of the 80% you don't need ).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style>
        .mymenus {
            top: 0;
            /* have tried various left/right/both margin combinations here */
            display: inline-flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            height: max-content;
            width: 100%;  /* 100% makes the right edge disappear 99% is workaround. */
            background: tomato; /* Not required - Just to see if background is showing */
            border-style: double;
            border: firebrick;
            position: fixed;
        }

        ul {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: larger;
            font-weight: bold;
            list-style: none; /* Gets rid of the bullet points */
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            border: violet;
            border-style: dotted;
            justify-content: space-evenly;  /* have to use justify content, not the text to get it to space evenly */
        }

        li {
            border: solid yellow;
            padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;  /* see impact of padding  */
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }

        #navbar_left {
            width: 70%;
            background: lightcyan;
            float: left;
        }
        #navbar_right {
            width: 30%;
            background: lightcyan;
            float: right;
        }
    </style>


    <title>SideBySide navbar</title>
</head>

<!-- have tried setting the right margin in body as well, impacts left side and content, but not right side of nav bar -->
<body>
    <!--Using this first div as a wrapper.  The padding means that the Text flow does not start right at the top which happens when you have a fixed element-->
    <div style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 90px;">
        <div class="mymenus">
            <nav id="navbar_left">
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="#" style="text-decoration-style: wavy;">Item One</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Item Two</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Item Three</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Item Four</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <nav id="navbar_right">
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="#" style="text-decoration-style: wavy;">Item One</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Item Two</a></li>
                        <!-- <li> <a href="#">Item Three</a></li> -->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>>

    </div>

    <div class="mytext>">
        <p>ipsum Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus sit repellendus dolorum corporis eius
            adipisci quam! Voluptate cupiditate iure, rem molestiae corrupti odit nesciunt, culpa qui ut sequi quasi
            eius?
        </p>


        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam facere itaque libero magnam natus nobis eum
            unde. Libero numquam, ab debitis animi cupiditate assumenda pariatur delectus et voluptatem at vel. Lorem
            ipsum
            dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quis excepturi voluptates ratione cupiditate expedita iusto
            magnam
            possimus aspernatur labore exercitationem earum repudiandae, cumque quae quam in eos esse asperiores a?
            Lorem
            ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima earum harum doloribus
            quos
            ut dolorum deleniti quam, tempora placeat sunt. Ad, culpa. Quam, expedita quisquam tenetur alias officia
            ducimus
            explicabo.
            Nihil nam suscipit ab accusamus unde eos explicabo temporibus impedit, dolore voluptatibus et nulla ipsum,
            rerum
            eum amet enim dolor sint commodi asperiores deserunt consectetur provident. Sed unde nulla minima.
            Quam unde illum quos! Cupiditate fugit debitis, blanditiis sapiente in similique maiores velit neque
            repudiandae
            officiis deleniti harum non tenetur nisi ea assumenda inventore numquam, necessitatibus illo. Quo,
            reprehenderit
            fuga?
            Consequuntur, non! Nesciunt adipisci quibusdam nemo pariatur vero fugit voluptatem porro dignissimos sit est
            ratione, exercitationem, odit corrupti magni blanditiis dolorem, deserunt repellat quas eius hic amet dicta!
            Totam, consequuntur!
            Suscipit earum, itaque dicta veniam vero, dolor in ipsa voluptatum facilis reprehenderit sed. Voluptates
            quos
            tenetur numquam, temporibus laboriosam ex consequuntur, nesciunt accusantium assumenda vel itaque, eius
            minima
            ad asperiores?
            Accusantium nostrum, quo suscipit laboriosam nisi, perspiciatis beatae quibusdam, consectetur odit corporis
            illum temporibus vero repellat sapiente in assumenda ab. Facere similique laborum odit neque explicabo
            consectetur fuga ad quia.
            Doloremque laudantium repellendus omnis amet quasi quisquam voluptatem inventore earum possimus,
            exercitationem,
            eius molestias officiis molestiae sed temporibus ea nisi. Asperiores dolore nam sint distinctio earum at
            magni
            voluptatem nobis.
            Adipisci rem inventore, repellat autem recusandae aut quis molestiae non, consequuntur voluptate veniam!
            Dolores, praesentium debitis. Sunt amet, atque voluptas similique quod vel, corporis laborum magni
            consequuntur
            dignissimos est iste?
            Quam ex ratione assumenda repudiandae, suscipit eos id odio voluptate eum accusantium labore nihil optio quo
            harum debitis laborum excepturi. Sed explicabo quibusdam obcaecati vero, aperiam sit earum. Officiis,
            cumque!
            Cumque nam odio exercitationem dignissimos similique facere magni maiores incidunt maxime ad explicabo,
            dolor
            recusandae tempore nihil dolore magnam repellendus dolorum eligendi libero esse labore sint aliquam minima.
            Et,
            atque! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi, suscipit. Aspernatur facilis fuga
            adipisci! Sed aut est, culpa quae corporis repudiandae, iusto quas facere rem minima dolores accusantium
            fugiat
            alias!
            Debitis odit corrupti id assumenda possimus, consequuntur inventore! Consequuntur eius tempore odio autem
            laudantium, nihil architecto, molestiae aspernatur, ducimus itaque excepturi vitae? Suscipit animi officia
            minima rem enim aspernatur modi.
            Dignissimos tenetur ad recusandae repudiandae deserunt nihil commodi delectus labore, sint minima tempora,
            sapiente illo. Quo consequatur vero nisi, nemo facilis natus numquam eos dicta repellat reprehenderit rerum
            adipisci excepturi!
            Beatae, molestiae quis quo veniam sint porro voluptatibus ullam labore voluptatem in consequatur quae vero
            deleniti alias! Ab ipsa, quas soluta cumque voluptatibus velit odio? Obcaecati ex architecto ipsa quod.
            Unde veniam quae aut corporis consequatur inventore explicabo dicta animi molestias. Debitis eius maiores
            molestias, eveniet, adipisci qui autem cumque repellendus tempore laudantium quas eum dolore quis aliquid!
            Eos,
            magni.
            Eligendi nam at debitis natus laboriosam nemo placeat quibusdam esse facere, nisi ratione doloremque fuga
            sequi
            magni nobis ipsam a, tempore odit dolorum? Esse odio illo veritatis doloremque error qui!
            Odit perspiciatis velit nisi at ipsam nobis doloremque voluptates incidunt minus corporis sed ex deleniti
            fugit,
            repudiandae error quia consequatur, provident est reiciendis facere modi minima sunt temporibus nam.
            Provident.
            Inventore tenetur eaque est qui, perferendis magnam nihil doloremque omnis, nulla recusandae, eum voluptas
            harum
            cupiditate sint officia quidem non. Animi asperiores consequuntur autem earum quod minus aut sint non.
            Qui tempore sapiente, ab, ipsa cupiditate porro id odit, harum nemo accusamus quisquam excepturi culpa.
            Laboriosam, doloribus. A dolore unde non nesciunt sapiente necessitatibus quam, at assumenda itaque quia
            deserunt?
            In accusantium deserunt aspernatur. Sit eos doloremque quae non recusandae cupiditate, sequi quaerat, magni
            quia
            odit, culpa vero molestiae deleniti perferendis provident officia voluptatum quos temporibus dolorem maxime
            dolores ad.
        </p>

        <p>ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae impedit voluptatibus soluta
            reprehenderit.
            Atque corporis odio nam repellat ratione nostrum placeat nobis, ex eaque eius ab earum consequuntur tenetur
            corrupti.
            Recusandae necessitatibus modi porro voluptas, quasi natus eaque nisi. Commodi est vitae accusantium. Dolor
            officia provident dignissimos totam. Excepturi mollitia, omnis non illum iusto numquam quisquam deleniti
            sequi
            nam eius!
            Fugit ab soluta non, corporis quisquam numquam minus incidunt similique hic necessitatibus repellat error
            tempora, nam atque labore. Ab sequi magnam provident laudantium molestias, eius est inventore consequatur
            consequuntur sed!
            Exercitationem blanditiis accusantium nam commodi hic quos voluptatibus, reiciendis ea quae aspernatur alias
            suscipit corporis odio quidem earum accusamus quia numquam eum temporibus eius libero fuga. Quasi
            praesentium
            modi itaque!</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Edit**
Thank to both Nick and Haworth.  The global heading were useful in cleaning up the layout and I understood the point about borders after playing around some more.

As far I can tell, 100vw/100% width + flex boxes + margins is just a bad combination!. It appears that stating 100% width and then adding in a margin or border makes the overall width go over 100% because as stated in the answers, they are outside the box.
So the solution appears to be leave the container alone(don't add any margins or padding ) and make the adjustment to the items within it to mask any issue or adjust the container size via a calculation.

A clearer head today plus better search terms also led me to this post:

[StackExchange - flex items and margins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32765039/using-margin-on-flex-items/32765152)

Answer (score 1):

There are some useful settings which you often find at the start of CSS files. They do three things, set the margin and padding on all elements to start off as 0, overriding the defaults that browsers may use, and in addition set box sizing to border-box which means borders etc are counted within an element’s dimensions, not additional to it.

If we do this with your snippet you’ll see that the right hand border of your navbar is visible. The 70% plus 30% are doing what you wanted, including their borders.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style>
* {
margin:0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
        .mymenus {
            top: 0;
            /* have tried various left/right/both margin combinations here */
            display: inline-flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            height: max-content;
            width: 100%;  /* 100% makes the right edge disappear 99% is workaround. */
            background: tomato; /* Not required - Just to see if background is showing */
            border-style: double;
            border: firebrick;
            position: fixed;
        }

        ul {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: larger;
            font-weight: bold;
            list-style: none; /* Gets rid of the bullet points */
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            border: violet;
            border-style: dotted;
            justify-content: space-evenly;  /* have to use justify content, not the text to get it to space evenly */
        }

        li {
            border: solid yellow;
            padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;  /* see impact of padding  */
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }

        #navbar_left {
            width: 70%;
            background: lightcyan;
            float: left;
        }
        #navbar_right {
            width: 30%;
            background: lightcyan;
            float: right;
        }
    </style>


    <title>SideBySide navbar</title>
</head>

<!-- have tried setting the right margin in body as well, impacts left side and content, but not right side of nav bar -->
<body>
    <!--Using this first div as a wrapper.  The padding means that the Text flow does not start right at the top which happens when you have a fixed element-->
    <div style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 90px;">
        <div class="mymenus">
            <nav id="navbar_left">
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="#" style="text-decoration-style: wavy;">Item One</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Item Two</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Item Three</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Item Four</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <nav id="navbar_right">
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="#" style="text-decoration-style: wavy;">Item One</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Item Two</a></li>
                        <!-- <li> <a href="#">Item Three</a></li> -->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>>

    </div>

    <div class="mytext>">
        <p>ipsum Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus sit repellendus dolorum corporis eius
            adipisci quam! Voluptate cupiditate iure, rem molestiae corrupti odit nesciunt, culpa qui ut sequi quasi
            eius?
        </p>


        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam facere itaque libero magnam natus nobis eum
            unde. Libero numquam, ab debitis animi cupiditate assumenda pariatur delectus et voluptatem at vel. Lorem
            ipsum
            dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quis excepturi voluptates ratione cupiditate expedita iusto
            magnam
            possimus aspernatur labore exercitationem earum repudiandae, cumque quae quam in eos esse asperiores a?
            Lorem
            ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima earum harum doloribus
            quos
            ut dolorum deleniti quam, tempora placeat sunt. Ad, culpa. Quam, expedita quisquam tenetur alias officia
            ducimus
            explicabo.
            Nihil nam suscipit ab accusamus unde eos explicabo temporibus impedit, dolore voluptatibus et nulla ipsum,
            rerum
            eum amet enim dolor sint commodi asperiores deserunt consectetur provident. Sed unde nulla minima.
            Quam unde illum quos! Cupiditate fugit debitis, blanditiis sapiente in similique maiores velit neque
            repudiandae
            officiis deleniti harum non tenetur nisi ea assumenda inventore numquam, necessitatibus illo. Quo,
            reprehenderit
            fuga?
            Consequuntur, non! Nesciunt adipisci quibusdam nemo pariatur vero fugit voluptatem porro dignissimos sit est
            ratione, exercitationem, odit corrupti magni blanditiis dolorem, deserunt repellat quas eius hic amet dicta!
            Totam, consequuntur!
            Suscipit earum, itaque dicta veniam vero, dolor in ipsa voluptatum facilis reprehenderit sed. Voluptates
            quos
            tenetur numquam, temporibus laboriosam ex consequuntur, nesciunt accusantium assumenda vel itaque, eius
            minima
            ad asperiores?
            Accusantium nostrum, quo suscipit laboriosam nisi, perspiciatis beatae quibusdam, consectetur odit corporis
            illum temporibus vero repellat sapiente in assumenda ab. Facere similique laborum odit neque explicabo
            consectetur fuga ad quia.
            Doloremque laudantium repellendus omnis amet quasi quisquam voluptatem inventore earum possimus,
            exercitationem,
            eius molestias officiis molestiae sed temporibus ea nisi. Asperiores dolore nam sint distinctio earum at
            magni
            voluptatem nobis.
            Adipisci rem inventore, repellat autem recusandae aut quis molestiae non, consequuntur voluptate veniam!
            Dolores, praesentium debitis. Sunt amet, atque voluptas similique quod vel, corporis laborum magni
            consequuntur
            dignissimos est iste?
            Quam ex ratione assumenda repudiandae, suscipit eos id odio voluptate eum accusantium labore nihil optio quo
            harum debitis laborum excepturi. Sed explicabo quibusdam obcaecati vero, aperiam sit earum. Officiis,
            cumque!
            Cumque nam odio exercitationem dignissimos similique facere magni maiores incidunt maxime ad explicabo,
            dolor
            recusandae tempore nihil dolore magnam repellendus dolorum eligendi libero esse labore sint aliquam minima.
            Et,
            atque! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi, suscipit. Aspernatur facilis fuga
            adipisci! Sed aut est, culpa quae corporis repudiandae, iusto quas facere rem minima dolores accusantium
            fugiat
            alias!
            Debitis odit corrupti id assumenda possimus, consequuntur inventore! Consequuntur eius tempore odio autem
            laudantium, nihil architecto, molestiae aspernatur, ducimus itaque excepturi vitae? Suscipit animi officia
            minima rem enim aspernatur modi.
            Dignissimos tenetur ad recusandae repudiandae deserunt nihil commodi delectus labore, sint minima tempora,
            sapiente illo. Quo consequatur vero nisi, nemo facilis natus numquam eos dicta repellat reprehenderit rerum
            adipisci excepturi!
            Beatae, molestiae quis quo veniam sint porro voluptatibus ullam labore voluptatem in consequatur quae vero
            deleniti alias! Ab ipsa, quas soluta cumque voluptatibus velit odio? Obcaecati ex architecto ipsa quod.
            Unde veniam quae aut corporis consequatur inventore explicabo dicta animi molestias. Debitis eius maiores
            molestias, eveniet, adipisci qui autem cumque repellendus tempore laudantium quas eum dolore quis aliquid!
            Eos,
            magni.
            Eligendi nam at debitis natus laboriosam nemo placeat quibusdam esse facere, nisi ratione doloremque fuga
            sequi
            magni nobis ipsam a, tempore odit dolorum? Esse odio illo veritatis doloremque error qui!
            Odit perspiciatis velit nisi at ipsam nobis doloremque voluptates incidunt minus corporis sed ex deleniti
            fugit,
            repudiandae error quia consequatur, provident est reiciendis facere modi minima sunt temporibus nam.
            Provident.
            Inventore tenetur eaque est qui, perferendis magnam nihil doloremque omnis, nulla recusandae, eum voluptas
            harum
            cupiditate sint officia quidem non. Animi asperiores consequuntur autem earum quod minus aut sint non.
            Qui tempore sapiente, ab, ipsa cupiditate porro id odit, harum nemo accusamus quisquam excepturi culpa.
            Laboriosam, doloribus. A dolore unde non nesciunt sapiente necessitatibus quam, at assumenda itaque quia
            deserunt?
            In accusantium deserunt aspernatur. Sit eos doloremque quae non recusandae cupiditate, sequi quaerat, magni
            quia
            odit, culpa vero molestiae deleniti perferendis provident officia voluptatum quos temporibus dolorem maxime
            dolores ad.
        </p>

        <p>ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae impedit voluptatibus soluta
            reprehenderit.
            Atque corporis odio nam repellat ratione nostrum placeat nobis, ex eaque eius ab earum consequuntur tenetur
            corrupti.
            Recusandae necessitatibus modi porro voluptas, quasi natus eaque nisi. Commodi est vitae accusantium. Dolor
            officia provident dignissimos totam. Excepturi mollitia, omnis non illum iusto numquam quisquam deleniti
            sequi
            nam eius!
            Fugit ab soluta non, corporis quisquam numquam minus incidunt similique hic necessitatibus repellat error
            tempora, nam atque labore. Ab sequi magnam provident laudantium molestias, eius est inventore consequatur
            consequuntur sed!
            Exercitationem blanditiis accusantium nam commodi hic quos voluptatibus, reiciendis ea quae aspernatur alias
            suscipit corporis odio quidem earum accusamus quia numquam eum temporibus eius libero fuga. Quasi
            praesentium
            modi itaque!</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The left and right nav bars combined take up 100% of the screen. The border is on the outside of the nav bars. The border takes up slightly more room. An example: `border: 500px solid black`
The above code will take up 500px outside of it's element on all four sides. The only difference between margin and border is with margin you can have a different value on all four sides of the element and with border the value is the same on all four sides.
In conclusion if you desire to fit the border on the screen consistently use a global constant like vw(view width) for the nav width and the border size.Or you could change left to 70% and right to 29% like you did. The only problem with this is that theoretically if the screen got small enough the border on the right wouldn't be on the screen. But it is unlikely that the screen will ever get that small.

Comment: “with border the value is the same on all four sides.“ I’m not sure I understand this as you can have different border widths on each side. Am I misunderstanding what you meant?

Comment: Border(length, style, width). It has only 3 parameters. I was just trying to compare it to margin to help iterate that border takes up space outside of the element. Even when you do border box. It's just the box contains the border of the element. You are right there is border-top, left, etc.